# Swift retain cycle or not

Tags: swift

can some one help me out for why not this is a retain cycle.
In my opinion,  self capture queue, and queue also capture the self. so it is a retain cycle.

but the following code in DemoAPP shows

```
------- operateOne queue async
------- operateOne safe lock
------- operateOne safe unlock
------- operateTwo queue async
------- operateTwo safe lock
------- operateTwo real set content
------- operateTwo safe unlock
------- operateOne real set content ==== 
deinit
```

The Demo class successfuly deinit, so it means self only capture queue. queue capture the content in block, and block capture self. so no retain cycle?

```
class Demo{
        private var queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.demo.ddd")
        private var safe: NSRecursiveLock = NSRecursiveLock()
    
        private var content = ""
        
        init() {
            
        }
        
        public func operateOne() {
            self.queue.async {
                print("------- operateOne queue async")
                self.safe.lock()
                print("------- operateOne safe lock")
    
                defer {
                    print("------- operateOne safe unlock")
                    self.safe.unlock()
                }
    //            self.content = ""
                self.queue.async {
                    print("------- operateOne real set content ==== \(self.content)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        public func operateTwo() {
            self.queue.async {
                print("------- operateTwo queue async")
                self.safe.lock()
                print("------- operateTwo safe lock")
    
                defer {
                    print("------- operateTwo safe unlock")
                    self.safe.unlock()
                }
                self.content = ""
                print("------- operateTwo real set content")
            }
        }
        
        deinit {
            print("deinit")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The *queue* doesn't capture `self`. The *closures* (tasks) that are executed on the queue do capture `self`:

```
self -> queue -> closure1 -> self
self -> queue -> closure2 -> self
```

However, they are removed from the `queue` after execution and the references to `self` stop existing:

```
self -> queue -> (empty)
```

Yes, there are strong reference cycles, but the cycles are only temporary.

Comment: thanks for your reply, is this means if self is not directly capture block, there will be not retain cycle, so no need to weak self

Comment: No, that's not true. The question is whether you want self to live until the whole queue is executed. That's the concept of a strong reference.